# Index and length must refer to a location within the string ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, substring, indexof

I have method

```
public static string UrlImageName(string name)
    {
        if (name.IndexOf("_180x140") <= 0)
        {
            var extPos = name.LastIndexOf(".");
            return name.Substring(0, extPos) + "_180x140" + name.Substring(extPos, name.Length);
        }
        return name;
    }
```

and view

```
<div class="car-img">
                <img src="@IKWelcomeScreenCellViewModel.UrlImageName(viewModel.SlideShowUrls[0])" />
            </div>
```

names are like this `"http://www.ua/Content/images/ik-main-page/Catalog.png"`
and I need this `http://www.ua/Content/images/ik-main-page/Catalog_180x140.png`

error Index and length must refer to a location within the string

Comment: please provide complete error.

Comment: Please do some research next time. There's already a question with the same exact title as yours.

Comment: I have tried but nothing can not help

Comment: thank you all of you... you are really helped me understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [**String.Insert**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Returns a new string in which a specified string is inserted at a specified index position in this instance.

So simply use

```
return name.Insert(extPos, "_180x140");
```

However as per your error is concerned use

```
return name.Substring(0, extPos) + "_180x140" + name.Substring(extPos);
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.Substring()` function takes the startingIndex as first argument and Length/number of characters tobe extracted as second argument.

Replace This:

```
return name.Substring(0, extPos) + "_180x140" + 
                                 name.Substring(extPos, name.Length);
```

With This:

```
return name.Substring(0, extPos.Length - extPos) + "_180x140" + 
                        name.Substring(extPos, name.Length - extPos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the second parameter to `Substring` is a length, this will fail every time unless `extPos` is 0:

```
name.Substring(extPos, name.Length);
```

Change it to this, so that you're only selecting the portion of the string *after* the period.

```
name.Substring(extPos + 1, name.Length - extPos - 1);
```

Or to this, if you want to *include* the period in the result:

```
name.Substring(extPos, name.Length - extPos);
```

You'll probably want an extra check too, if there's a chance there won't be a period in the string.

Comment: I need from this www.ua/Content/images/ik-main-page/Catalog.png

Comment: to this www.ua/Content/images/ik-main-page/Catalog_180x140.png

Answer (score 0):

`extPos` is the position where the extension of the file starts. Now, if you want to insert that `_180x140` just before the extension you could use Substring without the length.
This will take the remainder of the string starting from the `extPos` position and you don't need any calculation to readd the extension

```
public static string UrlImageName(string name)
{
    if (name.IndexOf("_180x140") < 0)
    {
        var extPos = name.LastIndexOf(".");
        return name.Substring(0, extPos) + "_180x140" + name.Substring(extPos);
    }
    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `extPos` is, let's say 5, and the string has 10 characters, then the following line will clip from index 5 to 15, which is out of bounds.

```
name.Substring(extPos, name.Length);
```

You should be doing this instead.

```
name.Substring(extPos, name.Length - extPos);
```

or, simply,

```
name.Substring(extPos);
```